# Correct sql query giving no results with php variable

Tags: php, sql

When the variable **$selectedname** is replaced with "test", the query outputs the correct data. 
When the variable **$selectedname** is used, the var_dump shows

**Var_dump Output**
[image]

**Database Table**

[image]

**Code**

```
  <?php
        echo "Selected Location";
?>
<br>
<?php
        $selectedname = $_POST['LocationName'];
        echo $selectedname;
?>
<br>
<?php
        require_once 'config.php';

        $sql = "SELECT Locationid, LocationName, Description FROM Location Where LocationName= '".$selectedname."' ";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo " id: " . $row["Locationid"]. " Name : " . $row["LocationName"]. " Description :" . $row["Description"]. "<br>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
            ?> <br> <?php
            var_dump($sql);
        }


        ?>
```

**Note**

1. I've tried enclosing the variable $selectedname in various ways with no luck.
2. I know that it is vulnerable to SQL injections at this time.
3. The **$selectedname** = a $post_['locationName'] is pulled from the database on a previous page. So it *should* match perfectly.

**Question**

1. Why doesn't the query work when the hard code is replaced with a variable and how can I fix it?

**Update!!!**

I removed spaces from the variable by using   $selectedname = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $_POST['LocationName']);

which solved the problem!

Comment: It seems, that the actual value of `$selectedname` is `' test'` (with space). Probably this is your issue. And you are right about the SQL injection - always use parameters in your statements.

Comment: You were correct! i used   $selectedname = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $_POST['LocationName']); to solve my issue! Thanks !

Comment: Your script is still unsafe. You must never assume that external data will come as you imagine. Maybe the script is not called from your website at all, but by some robot that sends you some data.

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: @ADyson yep, as i noted. It is vulnerable to SQL injection attackes for now.

Comment: Ok but why did you write it in an unsafe way to begin with, if you know that? It's no more difficult to write it safely the first time, and then you don't have to go back and re-test it all again after you've re-written the query.

Comment: @ADyson because I'm an amateur just trying to solve one problem at a time. How do i do it then ?

Comment: There are quite a few guides online which will show you. There are examples at the site I already linked you to (https://bobby-tables.com/php). https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli is also a reliable guide. And there are examples in the PHP documentation itself too: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php